# Why is this program outputting this number?

Tags: c++

I just starting learning C++.  Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    double hours,rate,pay;
    // get the number of hours worked
    cout << "How many hours did you work?";
    cin>> hours;
    //Get the hourly pay rate
    cout<<"How much did you get paid per hour?";
    cin>> pay;
    // calculates the pay
    pay = hours * rate;
    // Display the pay
    cout<<"You have earned $" << pay <<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I have no idea why this program is outputting the wrong numbers:

> How many hours did you work?19
>   How much did you get paid per hour?15
>   You have earned $4.03179e-313

Maybe I installed the IDE wrong (I am using Eclipse)?:

Comment: `rate` has not been initialized.

Comment: [Compile with warnings](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7922767807c2d9e5)

Comment: You could have used cppcheck, a static code analysis tool. It outputs: Cppcheck 1.75[test.cpp:7]: (style) Variable 'rate' is not assigned a value. [test.cpp:15]: (error) Uninitialized variable: rate Done!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your `cin >> pay` line is wrong, because you follow it up with `pay = hours * rate`.  Since rate is never assigned to, it just gets junk data in memory, so the output is undefined.  Change `cin >> pay` to `cin >> rate`

Answer (score 2):

There are two issues with your code.

1. Your second `cin>>` call is initializing `pay` when it should be initializing `rate` instead:

   ```
   cin >> rate;
   ```

   Or, if you are using C++11 or later, you can use `std::get_money()` instead:

   ```
   cin >> get_money(rate);
   ```
2. Your `cout<<` is outputting a `double` (a floating-point data type) using its *default* formatting, which may not be suitable for your needs.  To display money values, you should be explicit about the formatting, eg:

   ```
   cout << "You have earned $" << fixed << setprecision(2) << pay << endl;
   ```

   Or, if you are using C++11 or later, you can use `std::put_money()` instead:

   ```
   cout << "You have earned " << put_money(pay) << endl;
   ```

Answer (score 2):

firstly, initializing variables before using them is a good practice so you shoud try this :

```
double hours = 0, rate = 0, pay = 0;
```

secondly, you need to replace pay by rate in :

```
    //Get the hourly pay rate
cout << "How much did you get paid per hour?";
cin >> rate;
```

Amran AbdelKader.